# How can I use a loop inside a command?

Tags: shell-script, arguments, variable

I'm writing a shell script that contains a command that takes multiple directories as space-separated input arguments (like `ls`). I would like to fill in those arguments from a variable but don't know how to ensure words like "for" aren't interpreted as arguments. Here's an example that expresses my idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs="
 $HOME/Documents
 $HOME/Music
"

ls \
for dir in $dirs
do
    "$dir "
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In:

```
dirs="
  $HOME/Documents
  $HOME/Music
"
```

You're assigning a string (containing spaces and newline characters and whatever characters `$HOME` may contain) to a scalar variable (`$dirs`).

Then, you want to pass a list of directories to `ls`, that is several arguments. So you need somehow to split that string into a list of arguments to pass to `ls`. How are you going to split it? On spaces and newlines? What if `$HOME` contains spaces or newlines?

POSIX shells do have a splitting operator, actually they have a split+glob operator which you invoke by leaving a variable unquoted. Luckily enough, by default, the splitting is done on space and newline (and tab). So you could do:

```
IFS=' ''
' # space and newline
set -f # disable globbing as we want only the
       # splitting part of the split+glob operator
ls -- $dirs
```

But here, since we want a list, best would be to store the elements into a list-type variable instead of joining them into a string only to split it later.

POSIX shells have the array of positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`...) for that:

```
#! /bin/sh -
set -- ~/Documents ~/Music
ls -- "$@"
```

Or if you don't mind making your script slower and less portable, use a shell with array variables like `bash`:

```
#! /bin/bash -
files=(
  ~/Documents
  ~/Music
)
ls -- "${files[@]}"
```

Or `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
files=(
  ~/Documents
  ~/Music
)
ls -- $files
```

Comment: May have misunderstood OP, but: given `$dirs` as set by OP, why not just `ls -- $dirs` (variable not quoted)?

Comment: @grebneke, because that stops working when the filenames contain blanks or wildcard characters or start with `-`. If you want to store several things, you want arrays. If you use a scalar variable, then you need to start making assumptions.

Comment: Right. I was assuming the example given in the question which seems straight forward. Thanks.

Comment: @grebneke, even in this case, we don't know what `$HOME` contains. My `HOME` directory is `/All Volumes/v*/Stephane Chazelas`

Comment: I didn't know `${array[@]}` would return a space-separated list of the array's elements. That's a really simple solution and works perfectly!

Comment: @Cerran, it doesn't return a space-separated list, it returns a list of arguments. `ls` takes a list of files as arguments, not one argument with spaces in them to separate them. It's the shell role to take a command line and turn it into a list of arguments to pass to a command (by identifying words separated by spaces, or quoted...)

Comment: @Cerran - and note the double quotes: `"${array[@]}"`!